# Highest even number under main diagonal in a matrix. Solution for very big numbers?

Tags: c++, matrix

the program seems to be working just fine, but my lector told me that it wouldnt work in case i entered a very big negative number.he also told me it has something to do with the line max = a[i][j]. it can be figured out with one line of code, but since i am a pure beginner, i have no idea how to do it. 
this is the code

```
int a[10][10], i, j, n, max, amount = 0;
cout << "enter the type of square matrix (nxn) "; cin >> n;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        cout << "enter the element of matrix a[" << i << "][" << j << "]"; cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}

cout << "the matrix is " << endl;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        cout << setw(8)<<a[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

max = a[i][j];

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] > max) {
            if (a[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                if (i > j) {

                    max = a[i][j];
                    amount++;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if (amount > 0) {
    cout << "the highest even number under main diagonal is " << max;
}
else cout << "the number does not exist in this matrix " << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This site really isn't suited for getting help with your homework.  It is too difficult to conduct a proper tutorial, and if we just give you the answer, you won't learn anything.  Also, I do not understand from your description what this program is meant to do or what your lector thinks is wrong with it.  I recommend you go back to him and ask for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we can only speculate on what the lecturer's concerns are, some objective considerations can be done about the task of finding the biggest even number under the main diagonal in a matrix.

I'll focus only on the searching loop, not the overall implementation and other issues in OP's code, like out of bounds accesses.

When a range of values is scanned to find the maximum, we usually compare each element to a variable, let's say `max`, which holds the greater value found so far and which is updated when a bigger value is found. Some considerations should be kept in mind, though:

- The maximum may not exist. If the range is empty, we can't initialize `max` with the value of a particular element. There is no such element. In OP's case, for example, there could be no even number under the diagonal (actually, their error is that `max` is initialized with the value of an uninitialzed element, which could also be outside the allocated array).
- We can initialize `max` with the *lowest* possible value for the type of the elements. In case of `int` values, it's `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, which could be indeed a very big negative number (even, too). The problem is that this is a *valid* possible value, so if we check only for strictly greater values and we have *only* that value, we miss the maximum.

Also, in this particular case, instead of traversing the whole matrix checking if each element is under the diagonal, we can just traverse *only* the lower left part of the matrix.

The following snippet shows how those considerations could be taken into account:

```
#include <limits>

int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {  // only the elements of a square matrix under the diagonal
        if ( a[i][j] >= max  &&  a[i][j] % 2 == 0 ) {
            max = a[i][j];
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) pointed out in the comments, with a little change to the inner condition, it is possible to initializate `max` to a more handy value, like 0:

```
if ( (!found || a[i][j] > max)  &&  a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
//    ^^^^^^ checks if it's the first
```

Comment: @user3386109 To my understanding, that condition, alone, would set `max` to the first value encountered, ignoring it beeing even or odd (https://wandbox.org/permlink/ISKX76RIfvamRbWN), but yes, one could tweak the code to make the initialization unneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your code:

```
cout << "enter the type of square matrix (nxn) "; cin >> n;
```

You are not checking if `n <= 10` (10 is the size of your array `a`)

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

You are starting index from 1, whereas the array index starts from 0. You can write only a 9 X 9 matrix now into the array. And this will also result in a out of bounds exception when `i` reaches `n` and `n` is 10.

```
max = a[i][j];
```

Before the above statement, there is a for loop where `i` and `j` have been incremented to `n`. If `n` equals 10, this will result in an out of bounds exception.

And in the for loop after this you are doing the same mistake:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] > max) {
```